# Composer novo parametro config.platform

Tags: php, composer

Na última atualização do Composer `alpha11` foi introduzido um novo parâmetro para configurações independentes da versão da plataforma com o `config.platform` o que é genial.

Encontro pouca ou nenhuma documentação. Alguém me pode explicar a forma de utilização ou caso prático para dependências dentro do mesmo projeto para o php 7 e ou versões anteriores.